# How do I include global JS variables in JSP, before I include external JS using cq:include?

Tags: javascript, jsp, aem

I have a JS which uses some variables, which are coming either from OSGI or dialogs. So these need to be loaded before any of my JS, but the recommended cq:include tag loads the JS files before these. Any smart ideas?

```
<script> 
var globalVar ="<%=someJspVar%>";
</script>
<cq:includeClientLib js="something.that.uses.globalVar" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `dependencies` feature of AEM. You can specify your global js as a dependency of your component js. This means that AEM will include the global js before the component js in the generated html.

You can find more information in the [Adobe documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/the-basics/clientlibs.html#Linking).

Comment: But what if the global JS variables have a JSP value `<%=jspVar%>`? I cannot include them in an external script, so I cannot include them in dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Using client library dependencies is a good option, but if your global JavaScript isn't in a library but is instead rendered dynamically as in your example, this option may not work for you.  In such as case I recommend you make the code that depends on the global variables be inside a `ready` event.  That way it won't fire and begin the processing that depends on these global variables until everything is present and ready for use.

Example:

```
$(function() {
  // Code in your client library that depends on a variable with global scope
});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/ready/ for details on jQuery's ready event options.

Comment: The included clientLib includes third party JavaScript plug ins, I was looking for something which does not involve touching them.

Comment: Then maybe the "ready" event should lazy load the client library--so you don't modify any code, but instead just load it dynamically.  You could use https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/ to load your client library code from inside the "ready" function.

Comment: Agree with @Shawn's comment. Out of curiosity, why would a third party JS plugin depend on a jsp component's variable ?